# Which is compatible with most of the J2ME devices:- LWUIT or LCDUI?

Tags: mobile, java-me, lwuit, lcdui

I need to support as many J2ME devices as possible with my app. Which UI toolkit would I have the most success with ?(disregarding the actual implementation differences between the two such as LWUIT having better Graphic/Architecture)

Thanks!

Comment: you can also consider j2me polish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want most of the J2ME supported devices to run your app, You can use LCDUI. Although LCDUI can be used in a
wide range of mobile devices, it is
quite limited, and thus is best
suited for low-end to mid-tier
phones.

LWUIT ,on the other hand,works on almost all Java-me supported devices except a few old ones which do not support `MIDP 2.0/CLDC 1.1` .

Comment: So I can take from this that LCDUI will support all Java phones (but has limited capability) whereas LWUIT supports most phones and has better capabilities. So in answer to my question LCDUI supports the most phones correct?

Comment: Yeah! Also,LWUIT was released after LCDUI was. So older phones will not be able to support LWUIT as mentioned in my answer.